# Apple keeps refusing our app because they claim it uses HealthKit?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store, healthkit

All I ask for is to know how to identify the problem, we didn't add any reference to the health kit, though all our tries ended up with refusing the app from Apple (over a month now).

Their message:

> We noticed that your app uses HealthKit, but your app does not appear
>   to include any primary features that require health or fitness data.
>
> The intended use of HealthKit is to share health or fitness data with
>   other apps or devices, and it should be used only in apps that require
>   this data as a part of the app's core functionality.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please remove any HealthKit functionality from
>   your app, as well as any references to this app’s interactivity with
>   HealthKit from the app or its metadata.

here a screenshot of all the references in our iOS project:

[image]

inf.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>ar</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>en</string>
        <string>ar</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>icon-font.ttf</string>
        <string>DroidKufiRegular.ttf</string>
        <string>DroidKufiBold.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.3</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>my app</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>24</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2.2.1</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>myApp</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to camera to capture product images when adding a new auction</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to photo library to browse images when adding a new auction</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to photo gallary to browse images when adding a new auction</string>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.company.myApp</string>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires contacts access to share the application between contacts</string>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires calnder access to show users thier orders schedule</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires Microphone access to function properly</string>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires Apple Music access to function properly</string>
    <key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires Siri access to function properly</string>
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires bluetooth access to function properly</string>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>http://myapp.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Entitlements.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: In your terminal, goto your project, try this `fgrep -R health . ` . Dont forget to add dot in last. In result you got the file that have **health** keyword. Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I got same issue with advertisement. So I used this to identify where in project have advertisementIdentifier. It helped me. I developed native iOS app so I use Mac. Just try in you window, if command does not executed the try in mac. If result is none then it unable to find health. I cant be sure it works or not. But atleast try with your crossed fingers.

Comment: Have you solved you problem? There is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442764/xamarin-ios-build-rejected-due-to-healthkit-reference).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes, we solved it, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We could solve this problem by changing the Link Behavior to **Link Framework SDKs Only**, we tried this already before but this error was showing up:

> Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void
>   Xamarin.Forms.Log::Warning(System.String,System.String)', referenced
>   from the method 'System.Void
>   Xamarin.Forms.Pages.BaseDataSource/d__22::MoveNext()' in
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

We installed the package [Xamarin.Forms.Pages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Pages) into the iOS project, and the project was built successfully and the app got accepted from Apple- finally.