# Xamarin.ios build rejected due to HEALTHKIT reference

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, healthkit

My xamarin.ios build has been rejected from the app center due to reference of HEALTHKIT framework. I can't set linker to SDK framework only because of some 3rd party liberary. Also, I have uploaded a nee build with mtouch parameter "--linkskip=HealthKit", still my app got rejected 2nd time. Can anyone please guide me what more cahnges need to be done to remove the reference of HEALTHKIT framework from the application. Amy suggestion will be helpful

Comment: You need to enable the linker and then skip linking on your 3rd-party libs.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos

Comment: Hi Mayank, Did you solve the problem with HEALTHKIT? The same thing is happening to us. When we set the linker property to "SDK only", it removes HEALTHKIT but there are parts of the application that stop working. If we come up with a solution I'll share it here

Answer (score 4):

I had this recently, also tried what I could find online with no luck.

I used grep on the mac to find the said references :

```
 $ strings directory/Payload/UpCarePro.iOS.app/UpCarePro.iOS | grep Health
```

And then I removed packages one by one and rebuilt the project to find the one referencing it, once I no longer found any health reference in my project, I was able to pass Apple verification.

I had no new package causing this, and my app could pass the verification process many times before that, so I don't really understand how it started, but that's how I got rid of it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the given solution and got the following references of HealthKit:
HKHealthStore
HealthKitUI_HKActivityRingView_HKActivityRingViewAppearance
applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization:
HealthKitUI_HKActivityRingView_HKActivityRingViewAppearance

I tried deleting the packages from Visual Studio for Mac but, it's read-only. Could you please guide how and from which folder do I need to delete the references.

Comment: Directly from visual studio on the windows computer (in the case you use one), it's no fun to do but there is probably a nugget package creating these references, I didn't find a way to get the name of the culprit, so trial error is all I can suggest.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio for mac and unable to find the references of the Healthkit so that I can remove. I checked in my packages folder also but no luck. Also, I'm unable to find the place where and how the below permission is getting executed:

applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization: 

Any other way to remove the reference manually.

Comment: By any chance, are you using the LiveXAML nuget pacakge?  I had the same problem (Xamarin.ios build rejected due to HEALTHKIT reference
) and figured out that the newest versions of LiveXAML is causing the problem

Comment: @Patrick It was one of the nugget package I removed, but never thought it could cause this. I just tried to install it again and the reference of Health came back with it, good catch.

Comment: @MayankShrivastava Then you have to remove the nuget packages from the project one by one manually to check for healthkit references

Comment: I somehow managed to resolve this issue by changing the linker property to "SDK only" and add an additional mTouch argument to "--linkskip=assembely". I skip the assemblies which were creating issues when linker set to "SDK only".

Comment: @MayankShrivastava well good for you.  In my case, the "--linkskip=assembely" argument doesn't work for me, and I have to remove the related nuget packages from the project to get it working.

Comment: @Patrick Cool, but in my case HealthKit is inside Xamarin.iOS package. So, I wan't able to delete or remove it.